# MVC Delete Process

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Testing a Website. While logged in as an admin, the user should be able to delete a Service. A Service could have sub categories known as "Service Options" and below that "Service Option Items". When an admin tries to permanently delete a service he/she receives the following server error.

[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apFXm.png)

I have done some research and found out that the sub categories may need to be deleted first, and I believe the code reflects that.

Controller

```
 //
    // GET: /Service/Delete

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Service serviceToDelete = db.Services.Where(s => s.ServiceId == id).Single();
        return View(serviceToDelete);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Service/Delete

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirm(int id)
    {
        var serviceToDelete = db.Services.Where(s => s.ServiceId == id).Single();

        // remove the service option items
        var serviceOptionItems = db.ServiceOptionItems.Where(soi => soi.ServiceOption.ServiceId == serviceToDelete.ServiceId);
        foreach (var serviceOptionItem in serviceOptionItems)
        {
            db.ServiceOptionItems.Remove(serviceOptionItem);
        }

        // remove the service options
        var serviceOptions = db.ServiceOptions.Where(so => so.ServiceId == serviceToDelete.ServiceId);
        foreach (var serviceOption in serviceOptions)
        {
            db.ServiceOptions.Remove(serviceOption);
        }

        // remove the service
        db.Services.Remove(serviceToDelete);

        // save all changes
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { manage = "yes", mode = "all" });
    }
```

View

```
@model YardLad.Models.Domain.Service

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Delete Service";
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isConfirmed = false;

    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if (!isConfirmed)
        {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        isConfirmed = true;
                        $("#deleteService").submit();
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
 </script>

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this service?</h3>

<div class="display-label">Service Category</div>
<div class="display-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ServiceCategory.Name)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Name</div>
<div class="display-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Description</div>
<div class="display-field">
@if (Model.Description == null)
{
    @:No Description
}
else
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)
}

</div>

<div class="display-label">Base Price</div>
<div class="display-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BasePrice)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Is Active</div>
<div class="display-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsActive)
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Service", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "deleteService" }))
{
<p>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Delete" />
</p>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", new { manage = "yes" })
</div>


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete this service?" class="hidden">
<p>This service will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you     sure?</p>
</div>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using YardLad.Models.Domain;

namespace YardLad.Models.View
{
public class ServiceViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Service Id")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter a name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [UIHint("multilinetext")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Base Price")]
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Service Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select a category")]
    public int ServiceCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Active?")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Service options")]
    public List<ServiceOption> ServiceOptions { get; set; }
}

public class RequestServiceViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select a state")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select a service area")]
    public int ServiceAreaId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select a service")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please indicate the items selected")]
    public string[] SelectedServiceOptionItemIds { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please indicate the contractors available for the request")]
    public string[] AvailableContractorIds { get; set; }

    public State SelectedState { get; set; }
    public ServiceArea SelectedServiceArea { get; set; }
    public Service SelectedService { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceOption> SelectedServiceOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceOptionItem> SelectedServiceOptionItems { get; set; }
    public List<Contractor> AvailableContractors { get; set; }

    public int SelectedContractorId { get; set; }
    public Contractor SelectedContractor { get; set; }

    public int SelectedContractorServiceId { get; set; }
    public ContractorService SelectedContractorService { get; set; }

    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal SelectedContractorTaxRate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public bool UserIsLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public int UserAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address UserAddress { get; set; }
    public bool CreateCustomAddress { get; set; }
    public Address CustomAddress { get; set; }
}

public class SelectContractorViewModel
{
    public int ServiceAreaId { get; set; }
    public ServiceArea SelectedServiceArea { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public Service SelectedService { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceOption> ServiceOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceOptionItem> ServiceOptionItems { get; set; }

    public List<Contractor> AvailableContractors { get; set; }

    public Contractor SelectedContractor { get; set; }
    public int ContractorTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ContractorServiceId { get; set; }
    public ContractorService SelectedContractorService { get; set; }
    public List<ContractorServiceOption> ContractorServiceOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ContractorServiceOptionItem> ContractorServiceOptionItems { get; set; }

    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal SelectedContractorTaxRate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
}
```

Image of DB relations:
[edmx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IGZW.png)

Thank You for Reading

Comment: what is the question/ problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Service` is related to `ContractorService` as well and there must be some child records in there to cause the error you posted. You'll need to remove all of those children like you did the other tables, but you also need to set the child entity to `Deleted`:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirm(int id)
{
    var serviceToDelete = db.Services.Where(s => s.ServiceId == id).Single();

    // remove the service option items
    var serviceOptionItems = db.ServiceOptionItems.Where(soi => soi.ServiceOption.ServiceId == serviceToDelete.ServiceId);
    foreach (var serviceOptionItem in serviceOptionItems)
    {
        db.ServiceOptionItems.Remove(serviceOptionItem);
        db.Entry(serviceOptionItem).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    // remove the service options
    var serviceOptions = db.ServiceOptions.Where(so => so.ServiceId == serviceToDelete.ServiceId);
    foreach (var serviceOption in serviceOptions)
    {
        db.ServiceOptions.Remove(serviceOption);
        db.Entry(serviceOption).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    // remove the contractor services
    var contractorServices = db.ContractorServices.Where(so => so.ServiceId == serviceToDelete.ServiceId);
    foreach (var contractorService in contractorServices)
    {
        db.ContractorServices.Remove(contractorService);
        db.Entry(contractorService).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    // remove the service
    db.Services.Remove(serviceToDelete);

    // save all changes
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { manage = "yes", mode = "all" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key constraint on the tables `Service`, `ServiceOptions` and `ServiceOptions`. Thus you will have to delete all the `ServiceOptionsItems` and `ServiceOptions` of that service before you can delete the `service`.

But if you have such requirement, I suggest you use `ON DELETE CASCADE` while adding the constraint. So that it will allow you to directly delete the service and will delete all the child `ServiceOptions` and `ServiceOptionsItems` automatically.

More Info: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: Thank You for taking time out to help me. I thought the for each loop would cycle through and remove each one before moving to the next?                                                                       
        foreach (var serviceOptionItem in serviceOptionItems)
        {
            db.ServiceOptionItems.Remove(serviceOptionItem);
        }

Comment: It should but I would be able to say more only when you post the error message you are getting. Its not there in your question. If its the same error that I have assumed, you can try to do save changes after each loop.

Comment: I added a image of the server error in the original post.

Comment: Yup thats the problem. Did you try adding SaveChanges() after query for each table?. Anyways, why do you want to do it by your code. It is not efficient. Everytime you will make a connection with the DB, find the rows and delete. Let the DB do it for you.

Comment: Yes, right after all the for each loops I have " db.SaveChanges();"

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you have the association between `Service` and something called `ContractorService`. Delete the related `ContactorService` entities first or remove or change its `ServiceId` value.